# RandomNumberGenerator proper usage

Tags: c#, random

I would like to generate a salt using a secure PRNG. I've read that the newest and recommended way to achieve this is to create a `RandomNumberGenerator` instance to `GetBytes`. However, I am not so sure which way should I follow:

```
// CODE 1

private static byte[] GenerateSaltNewInstance(int size)
{
    using (var generator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        var salt = new byte[size];
        generator.GetBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
}

// CODE 2

private static RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

private static byte[] GenerateSaltStatic(int size)
{
    var salt = new byte[size];
    rng.GetBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}
```

What is the difference? Basically in the first version of this method I am creating a new instance of `RandomNumberGenerator` every time. In the second one I am using a static instance initialized once.

Which one should I choose? In articles I see people following the first path, but I don't feel why it would be a better idea to create `RandomNumberGenerator` 10000 times :P Does it make it more secure to use a new instance each time?

Comment: I doesn't really make a difference if the random number generator is truly random.  It is more efficient to make the variable static.  The long you let a random generator run the is not truly random the better chance of being able to break the pattern.  So making the random generator local will restart the random number generator with a new seed each time the constructor is called.  If you don't care about somebody breaking the pattern then calling the random number generator constructor once will probably give better random results.

Comment: My probability teacher use to ask the question : If you had something random and then randomize it a 2nd time do you get something that is more random or less random.  The answer is probably something less random.  So calling the constructor multiple times will give something less random.

Comment: @jdweng Execpt that both are just wrappers for the CSP API in windows and they both pull from a singular static pool of randomness (in the current version of .NET because `Create()` uses `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` by default in the current version.)

Comment: jdweng, so your probability teacher believes that if I throw dice and, without looking at them, pick them up and throw them again, their outcome is more predictable than if I had just checked them after the first throw?  I'd have debated him on it.  The probability does not change.  Now with a PRNG as opposed to true randomness (if the latter even actually exists), things are not so simple, and it *might* be possible to accidentally reduce the entropy by rolling many times.  Depends on the internals of the generator.  As for the original question, I always make 1 PRNG for the whole program.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first method is guaranteed to be thread safe, the 2nd depends on the thread safety of the object returned by the `Create()` method.

In the current implementation of .NET (as of 2015) it returns `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` and that type is safe to call `GetBytes` from multiple threads at the same time but it is not guaranteed that the default `Create()` will always return a `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` in future versions of the framework. The safer option is just create it as needed or use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` directly and have the guarantee of thread safety.

Security wise they should both be just as secure both call down to the [Crypto Service Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386986(v=vs.85).aspx) which will just grab the most random number as possible that your hardware supports.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to think that the static method `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(size)` is the preferred way to go, but I'm not sure.